# Qt QByteArray size

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I need to add to a `QByteArray` 4 bytes, as frame. (struct ([4 bytes][message]))

I do:

```
 QByteArray byteArray;
 QByteArray byteArray2(man.SerializeAsString().c_str(), man.ByteSize()); // 31 byte
 qDebug()<<byteArray.size()<<"size"; // 0 bytes
 byteArray.resize(3); 
 qDebug()<<byteArray.size()<<"size"; // 3, ok
 byteArray.append(man.ByteSize()); 
 qDebug()<<byteArray.size()<<"size"; // 4
 byteArray2.prepend(byteArray);     
 qDebug()<<byteArray2.size()<<"size"; // return 35, ok
 qDebug()<<(byteArray2); // not print my message
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to print a string that (should) start with `\0` characters (binary zero). `qDebug()` will most likely not print anything at all - `\0` is a string terminator.

But there's a bug in your code, you should be doing:

```
 byteArray.fill(0, 3);
```

instead of the `resize` call, otherwise you'll get random data in the first bytes.

Comment: To print binary data, one can use QByteArray::toHex()